# Second-order ordinary differential equation with linear form of coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this?

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y(x)+(C_{1}+C_{2}x)\frac{d}{dx}y(x)+(C_{3}+C_{4}x)y(x)=C_5$$ 
where, $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_4$ and $C_5$ are non-zero constants.

"Handbook of Differential Equations" , 3rd edition by Zwillinger mentions a similar form but the homogeneous one in 3rd equation of section no. 27. However, I could not follow it properly, therefore asked here.

Comment: With $C_5 = 0$ (homogeneous) the solution can be obtained with Hermite and Hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Thanks @Cesareo. How to proceed if $C_5$ $\ne$ $0$?

Comment: You can use the variation of constants method (Lagrange).

Comment: Thanks again @Cesareo! Will you please suggest some reference? Since I am a beginner and an off-field person, I could not follow what was given in the reference I mentioned with the question. However I will try as suggested by you.